# Realm migration - adding new class to the existing Realm module

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

I am adding an existing class **Headings.class** to RealmModule **NoteModule**
This class is not part of any of my several Realm Modules before.
How to write Realm migration code to achieve this?

NoteModule:

```
@RealmModule(classes = {PaperEntry.class, BookEntry.class, AccessInfo.class, BookInfoEntry.class, Heading.class})
public class NoteModule {
}
```

I couldn't find examples for my question here at stackoverflow.

Appreciate the support.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations) link for Realm Migration.

Change realm configuration like this and create new class like `MyMigration.java`

```
Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                    .name("database.realm").schemaVersion(1).migration(new MyMigration()).build();

Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

MyMigration.java

```
public class MyMigration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {

        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

        if (oldVersion == 1) {
            schema.create("Headings")
                    .addField("make", String.class)
                    .addField("model", String.class)
                    .addField("primaryKEY", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY);
            oldVersion++;
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I hope the above code is for adding a new Realmobject, but my question is - my Realmobject is already existing and I want to add to it one of my several RealmModules. Anyway I tried your code but getting error "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.realm.RealmObjectSchema io.realm.RealmObjectSchema.addField(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, io.realm.FieldAttribute[])' on a null object reference"

May be my question was not clearer. Let me edit it.